# Disabling WebSockets compression and xor mask on the Browser side

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I use "WS" library in my NodeJS project. It is possible to disable compression? I'm trying to do this on the server side

```
ws = new WebSocketServer({port: 8889, perMessageDeflate: false})
```

but it does not work

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
```

And I have no idea what can i do to disable xor mask.

Comment: if you don't want to use compression extension, you should disable it from client side!

Comment: The client is a browser in my case. I do not know how to disable it on the browser side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have disabled per message deflate in the server, however you are seeing that the client is announcing its capability of handling it, this is normal. I mean, that HTTP headers you have pasted are from the client request (because a server does not send `Accept-*` headers).

To know if compression was finally selected as extension for the connection, check the `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions` header in the server response.

XOR masking cannot be disabled, it is required from client to browser to mitigate some possible attacks and proxies doing funny things: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/226343/is-masking-really-necessary-when-sending-from-websocket-client

Comment: You're right. Server does not return `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions` header and there is no compression. My mistake.

Comment: It's strange that you can not disable xor masking. I am using https and I think it should solve the problem without xor.

Comment: Oh yes that right. Actually websocket frames have a bit to indicate masking, so it is technically possible, and using https it would be safe enough, but... requirements :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add the Compression: None header — otherwise, the browser requires Sec-WebSocket-Extensions with permessage-deflate.